# Does Hibernate has a specific condition for naming columns that start with the same letter?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm using spring boot and jpa hibernate to create some tables in my database but it throws a weird exception which i don't really understand.

```
@Entity
public class Option {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String marca;
    private String model;
    private String anFabrDeLa;
    private String anFabrPanaLa;
    private String pretDeLa;
    private String pretPanaLa;
    private String oras;
    private int score;
    //constructors, getters and setters

}

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'option (id integer not null, an_fabr_de_la varchar(255), an_fabr_pana_la varchar' at line 1
```

I've tried to use `@Column(name='something')` and it still gives me this weird error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

option and options are keywords that used by MySQL. Please use some different name.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`option` is a [MySQL keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html). Choose another table name.

Answer (score 1):

As people already said, you're using a MySql reserved keyword for your table name.
If you want to keep your class name but want to rename your table you have to add

```
@Table(name="something") // This will explicitly set the table name.
@Entity
public class Option {
   ...
}
```

Or if you really wish to keep both class name and table name you have to put the table name between ` marks:

```
@Table(name="`option`")
@Entity
public class Option {
   ...
}
```